# Inverse Clarification

Tags: inverse

I just learned Inverse Variation. I'm a bit confused with it but I need some clarification. Is it the same as inverse functions and numbers? For example, $0.1 = 10$. Is the Inverse Variation what I think it is?

Comment: $0.1$ is certainly not equal to $10$.

Comment: As in it is the inverse.